# Power BI: How to create different tables from the original one with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've got the following table with data in an Excel file

```
YEAR TEAM SPORT  POINTS
2001 A    Basket 20
2001 A    Soccer 17
2002 A    Basket 35
2002 A    Soccer 23
2001 B    Golf   45
2003 B    Soccer 20
2001 C    Basket 47
```

I got the data into Power BI after loading the table through 'Get data'. Now I have a table called 'Points', which I would like to handle to obtain different visualizations: a graph with the evolution of the points of the Basket-A team over the years, a comparison of the points of the same year for the same sport, etc.

I like Python code and, within "Power Query Editor > Transform > Run Python Script", I did run:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df1 = data[(data.TEAM == 'A') & (data.SPORT == 'Basket')]
```

Hower, my 'Points' table is now just the contents of 'df1' (it was overwritten with just the selected data when TEAM='A' and SPORT='Basket').

My purpose is creating, from the 'data' dataframe, several 'dfX' dataframes in order to make the visualizations based on these new 'dfX'

I would like to know how to:

- if this is a smart approach (loading the Excel file, handling the data with Python to create the tables to visualized)
- How to create different tables (the original 'Points', 'df1', 'df2'. etc), instead of just overwriting the original 'Points' table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the smart approach for you use-case of creating multiple tables from same database is

- creating one main table/query in PowerBI from Excel and then
- [referencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries) it to create copies and apply your filters accordingly

Referencing a "Main-Query" to create a "Reference-Query" ensures that any change in the Main-Query gets reflected in Reference-Query. And then you can make further changes to the new Reference-Query

Additional Resources:

- [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_JHm-b3Jes)
- [Online article](https://www.powerbitraining.com.au/duplicate-vs-reference-queries/)